# Mysqli query function insert duplicate lines

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, insert, duplicates

I have been trying to insert a new line to mysql db but insert(){...} function has inserted duplicate lines.

I also have tried several methods to insert but it doesn't works. All of the methods have inserted duplicate rows .

How can I fix the problem? Do you have any idea?

Thank you for your help & advice.

```
protected $db;

public function __construct() {
    try {
        $this->db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'trigger');
        $this->db->set_charset("utf8");

    } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
        throw new SmartyException('Mysql Resource failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
}

public function select($table, $rows = "", $where = "", $return_type = "") {
    if (empty($rows)) {
        $rows = "*";
    }
    if (empty($where)) {
        $where = "";
    } else {
        $where = "where " . $where;
    }

    try {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT $rows FROM $table $where");
        if ($return_type == "json") {
            return json_encode($query);
        } else {
            return $query;
        }
    } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $exc) {
        return $exc->getMessage();
    }
}

public function insert($table, $params) {
    $_keyArr = array();
    $_valueArr = array();

    foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
        $_keyArr[] .= $key;
        $_valueArr[] .= $value;
    }

    $keys = implode("`,`", $_keyArr);
    $values = implode("','", $_valueArr);

    $query = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `$table` (`$keys`) VALUES('$values')");

    try {
        return $query;
    } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $ex) {
        return $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

-------------Answer to matt-------------

I call with following code:

```
    if ($this->db->insert("table_name", array("path" => "test", "flow_name" => "test"))) {
        echo 'ok';
    } else {
        echo 'not ok';
    }
```

-------------Answer to Pavel-------------

"REPLACE INTO" didn't work. The problem occured again.

Comment: May I ask how you call this function?

Comment: what is this? `$_keyArr[] .= $key; $_valueArr[] .= $value;` only use `[] =` not `[] .=`

Comment: Nothing in the code you posted will create duplicates. If you call the `insert()` function multiple times with the same parameters, it will create duplicates.

Comment: Your `try/catch` block looks more than a little hinky!! `return $query` will not throw an exception, while `$query = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO \`$table\` (\`$keys\`) VALUES('$values')");` quite posibly might

Comment: If your table does not have a unique column set, there is nothing to stop it creating duplicate rows if you run with the same test data more than once. **Please add the tables definitions for the tables in question**

Comment: might be useful to know what $this->db->query() does

Comment: @nowhere: There you go: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 0):

Just use REPLACE INTO instead INSERT INTO

```
$query = $this->db->query("REPLACE INTO `$table` (`$keys`) VALUES('$values')");
```